# Finding elements in std::set

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdset

Given that I have a `std::set`, how do I find out if one element of the set is before the other. For example, something like this -

```
bool before(const std::set &s, const int first, const int second) const {
  auto it_first = s.find(first);
  auto it_second = s.find(second);
  return it_first <= it_second;
}
```

The above code does not work since `<=` is not defined for the bidirectional iterators, but how would one go about doing something like this?

Comment: Sets doesn't allow equal elements, so you don't need <= operator, just < operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `set` orders its elements by `operator<` (by default). The comparator itself can be retrieved via [`key_comp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/key_comp) or [`value_comp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/value_comp). So if both elements are in the set, the order is defined by the elements themselves - you don't need the iterators:

```
return s.key_comp()(first, second);
```

If one or neither are in the set, then it depends on what you want to do in those cases:

```
if (s.count(first)) {
    if (s.count(second)) {
        return s.key_comp()(first, second);
    }
    else {
        /* no second */
    }
}
else {
    /* no first, possibly second */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would look more generic solution than only for `std::set` this method would work for any container with `forward` iterator:

```
template <class T>
bool before( const T &cont, typename T::const_iterator first, typename T::const_iterator second )
{
    for( auto it = cont.begin(); true; ++it ) {
        if( it == first ) return true;
        if( it == second ) return false;
    }
 }
```

assuming `first` and `second` are valid iterators. Now you can have more optimal specialization for `std::set` and `std::map`:

```
return cont.key_comp()( *first, *second );
```

and for container with random access iterator:

```
return first < second;
```

Comment: this is an O(n) check... Since I am using a std::set, I would like to do it in less than that. Otherwise why not use a std::vector